# Cmd Calculator loop command

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe, calculator

Im still in school and want to troll my friends.
Every time we are on the pc's people are spamming de calculator key so they get a screen full of calculators.
Now I want to make a command with cmd to make this key loop.
So when I activate this loop it whill open the caculator till I want to stop it.
Is there any way how to make such command.

We are on windows 7
I dont have admin command but I acces to the cmd.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

In order to start multiple calculators at once, use the following command:

```
for /L %%a IN(1,1,20) DO start "" "C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe"
```

The for command will start calc 20 times. Change the 20 to any number.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch script with the following content repeated as many times as you want:

```
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
```

Then save it as .bat and execute it. It should open a calculator for every line you wrote in the script.

Comment: I just tried it. It just opens one calculator. Then when I close the calculator it opens a new one. Is it possible to open all the calculators at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the START command to run each program asynchronous:

```
START C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
START C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
START C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
```

Funny thing is to create following BATCH file (`funny.bat`):

```
@echo off
START C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
funny.bat
```